# Firefox addon/extension for saving code snippets?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Does anyone know  of a Firefox addon/extension for saving code snippets ?

Comment: +1 Just to save code snippets? Sounds a great idea! We could build it from scratch... Count with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's no Firefox addon you may want to give [snippets.me](http://snippets.me/) a try. I recently got invited and now work with it. It's still under development. But already quite advanced. It's a small app for Windows and Mac. Coolest features to me by now: Syncing to online account, code hightlighting, works with Sublime and other IDE. Best: it's free. One of the future features: snippets sharing.

Comment: I know this answer is really old, but I got here by searching google for something like this and wanted to let anyone know that this link no longer works, it is just a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Fast Googleing gave me this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/

Answer (score 1):

For managing code snippets I recommend a small text snippet tool named Clippings https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clippings/

After adding a new entry you can easily insert your snippet anywhere inside Firefox or even Thunderbird via a customized keyboard shortcut